# Disposing scoped methods

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, asp.net-core-5.0

BinanceSpotClient instantiates `BinanceClient` and `BinanceSocketClient`. They have to be disposed when LiveTradeManager has finished executing. I put a breakpoint onto the Dispose method and it was currently not executed. Do I have to manually call it by making LiveTradeManager inherit IDisposable and then call BinanceSpotClient.Dispose?

```cs
services.AddScoped<LiveTradeManager>();
services.AddScoped<PaperTradeManager>();
services.AddScoped<ITradeManagerFactory, TradeManagerFactory>();

services.AddScoped<IExchangeClientFactory, ExchangeClientFactory>();
```

```cs
public interface ITradeManager
{
    Task RunAsync();
}

public class LiveTradeManager : ITradeManager
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IExchangeClient _exchangeClient;

    public LiveTradeManager(ILogger logger, IExchangeClientFactory exchangeClientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _exchangeClient = exchangeClientFactory.GetExchangeClient(exchangeOptions.Value.Exchange);
    }
    
    ...
}

public interface IExchangeClientFactory
{
    IExchangeClient GetExchangeClient(Exchange exchange);
}

public class ExchangeClientFactory : IExchangeClientFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ExchangeClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IExchangeClient GetExchangeClient(Exchange exchange)
    {
        return exchange switch
        {
            Exchange.BinanceSpot => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<BinanceSpotClient>(_serviceProvider) ?? throw new NullReferenceException(),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(exchange), exchange, null)
        };
    }
}

public class BinanceSpotClient : IExchangeClient, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IBinanceClient _client;
    private readonly IBinanceSocketClient _socketClient;

    public BinanceSpotClient(ILogger logger, IOptions<ExchangeOptions> exchangeOptions)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        _client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions()
        {
            ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(exchangeOptions.Value.ApiKey, exchangeOptions.Value.SecretKey),
            AutoTimestamp = true,
            AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            TradeRulesBehaviour = TradeRulesBehaviour.AutoComply
        });

        _socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions()
        {
            ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(exchangeOptions.Value.ApiKey, exchangeOptions.Value.SecretKey),
            AutoReconnect = true,
            ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
        });
    }
    
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_client != null)
            {
                _client.Dispose();
            }

            if (_socketClient != null)
            {
                _socketClient.UnsubscribeAll();
                _socketClient.Dispose();
            }

            _subject.OnNext(Observable.Never<Unit>());
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills, I have `services.AddScoped<IExchangeClientFactory, ExchangeClientFactory>();` registered with the container.

Comment: [ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) don't register the instance in the service cope. Then the instance created by this method isn't disposed. More information : [Use dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: @Vernou, now I understood mate, thanks a lot! If you want, type it as an answer. It calls the Dispose method with `Exchange.BinanceSpot => _serviceProvider.GetService<BinanceSpotClient>() ?? throw new NullReferenceException(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to manually call it by making LiveTradeManager inherit
> IDisposable and then call BinanceSpotClient.Dispose?

If you don't want to register IExchangeClient with the container, basically yes.

Considering registering `IExchangeClient` with the [container](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). If the container doesn't know about it, it can't call `Dispose` for you. Which means it becomes your job to do it.

The general problem with the explicit factory pattern approach (which you are using here) is exactly what you are experiencing. Which is why I prefer Autofac's approach (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html / https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) - disposal is the container's problem, so you let the container **be the factory** so it knows when disposal is needed

The key to understand is that with your current code the container knows about the factory but **not** what is going on *inside* the factory. **You** can look at the code and see something needs disposing but the container **can't**. The container will dispose the *factory* if **it** implemented `IDisposable` - but not *the stuff the factory is creating*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, you are correct. Like @Vernou said in the comments. the problem is that `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<BinanceSpotClient>()` doesn't register BinanceSpotClient to the container whereas `_serviceProvider.GetService<BinanceSpotClient>()` with `services.AddScoped<BinanceSpotClient>();` does. That fixed the problem. I currently don't want to use Autofac, but thanks for your offer.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said in my comments and answer. `Considering registering IExchangeClient with the container.`.

Comment: To be clear though, you should likely _not_ be using the solution that it sounds like you have decided to use. You should remove `ExchangeClientFactory` altogether, and inject the client directly, not the factory.

Comment: I understand that I currently have only x1 exchange (BinanceSpotClient) but I'm about to have more exchanges, which means I would really need the factory method. It's just like https://medium.com/null-exception/factory-pattern-using-built-in-dependency-injection-of-asp-net-core-f91bd3b58665

Comment: Honestly, consider looking at a more capable IoC container. But the factory approach will "work" well enough for you for now. Great to hear you got it working!